# Subscribing on mqtt topic with tls encryption (PYTHON)

Tags: python-3.x, ssl, mqtt, tls1.2, paho

I have several server that communicates through the mqtt broker, but to secure the communication between them, I secure the mqtt broker with tls, and via dedicated interface of these servers, I could configure them so that he could use the mqqt broker.

**here is my mqtt folder:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

here is an example of the configuration of one of my servers to encrypt and decrypted to the mqtt broker :

[image]

So, I had a python script that communicated via mqtt with one of the servers, but now that I have secured the mqtt broker, I can not communicate with my script, I must also added tls in my script python :

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt #import the client1
import time
import json
import requests
import ssl


#phy = "" #phypayload extrait de la tram


def on_log(client, userdata, level, buf) :

    #print("log: "+buf)
    k=0
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc) :

  if rc==0:
       print("connected ok")
  else:
       print("not connected", rc)
 #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 def on_disconnect(client, userdata, flags, rc=0) :
    print("disconnect result code "+str(rc))
 #-------------------------------------------------------------------------
 def on_message(client,userdata,msg) :

   global m_decode
   topic=msg.topic
   m_decode=str(msg.payload.decode("utf-8","ignore")) 

   print("message received :  ",m_decode)
   print('')
   print("send to paclido server :")
   print('')
   print("PHYPAYLOAD",phy)


    #---------------------------------------------------------------------


   broker_address="127.0.0.1:1883"

   client = mqtt.Client("paclido") #create new instance
   client.on_connect=on_connect
   client.on_disconnect=on_disconnect
   client.on_log=on_log
   client.on_message=on_message

   #######can't configure tls ? how i'm suppose to do ? ##########
   client.tls_set('/etc/mosquitto/certs/ca/ca.crt', tls_version=1)
   client.tls_insecure_set(True)
   ###############################################################

   print ("cnct to broker", broker_address)
   client.connect("127.0.0.1", 8883, 60)
   client.subscribe([("gateway/abcdef1010101010/rx", 0)("gateway/a10b20c20d30e40f/rx", 0)])
   client.loop_forever()
```

You can see that in my code I tried to configure the tls, but it does not work, I saw the documentation, but I can not, here is the log of my python:

[image]

Can some one help me to configure my python script ? thanks !

Comment: try removing the `tls_version=1` from the `tls_set` function

Comment: I removet it , but always =====> 
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:720)

Comment: when i comment the tls line code, i have :  cnct to broker 127.0.0.1:8883
disconnect result code 0
disconnect result code 0
disconnect result code 0